# Creating Unique Names

Tags: python, pdf, repository

I'm creating a corpus from a repository. I download the text from the repository in pdf, convert these to text files, and save them. However, I'm trying to find a good way to name these files.

To get the filenames I do this: (the records generator is an object from the Sickle package that I use to get access to all the records in the repository)

```
for record in records:
            record_data = []  # data is stored in record_data
            for name, metadata in record.metadata.items():
                for i, value in enumerate(metadata):
                    if value:
                        record_data.append(value)
            file_path = ''
            fulltext = ''
            for data in record_data:
                if 'Fulltext' in data:
                    fulltext = data.replace('Fulltext ', '')
                    file_path = '/' + os.path.basename(data) + '.txt'
                    print fulltext
                    print file_path
```

The print statements on the two last lines:

```
https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/34910/1/Bertelsen-Master.pdf
/Bertelsen-Master.pdf.txt
https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/34912/1/thesis-output.pdf
/thesis-output.pdf.txt
https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/9976/1/gartmann.pdf
/gartmann.pdf.txt
https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/34174/1/thesis-mariusno.pdf
/thesis-mariusno.pdf.txt
https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/9285/1/thesis2.pdf
/thesis2.pdf.txt
https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/9360/1/OMyhre.pdf
```

As you can see I add a .txt to the end of the original filename and want to use that name to save the file. However, a lot of the files have the same filename, like thesis.pdf. One way I thought about solving this was to add a few random numbers to the name, or have a number that gets incremented on each record and use that, like this: thesis.pdf.124.txt (adding 124 to the name).

But that does not look very good, and the repository is huge, so in the end I would have quite large numbers appended to each filename. Any smart suggestions on how I can solve this?

I have seen suggestions like using the time module. I was thinking maybe I can use regex or another technique to extract part of the name (so every name is equally long) and then create a method that adds a string to each file pased on the url of the file, which should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is to compute a unique hash of the files, e.g. with MD5 or SHA1 (or any other), cf. [this article](http://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-files-with-python/). For a large number of files this can become quite slow, though.

But you don't really see to touch the files in this piece of code. For generating some unique id, you could use [uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) and put this somewhere in the name.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, will use the uuid package, always interesting to see that python core has most of what you need!